# ¿Cómo corregir el error expected initializer before 'std'?

Tags: c++

Ando incursionando en esto de la programación y creo que me metí demasiado aprendiendo por mi cuenta que parece que no aprendí nada, ando haciendo códigos de diversas cosas pero ahora mismo tope con este problema que no logro solucionar y solo me aparece lo siguiente al compilar.

Lo que intento hacer es conseguir como resultado múltiples combinaciones de 6 números pero trato de que cumplan condiciones como; si son números primos, números compuestos, que vayan del 1 al 56, y además que las combinaciones finales sean menores o mayores a ciertos números que yo diga.

Los problemas que me especifica son:

> Linea 9 C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\CPP\Untitled1.cpp   [Error] expected initializer before 'std'
>
> Linea 52 C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\CPP\Untitled1.cpp  [Warning] control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Y este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>

int main()

std::vector<int> primes {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53};
std::vector<int> composites {4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56};
std::vector<int> valid_numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 12, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 52, 56};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> all_combinations;

void get_combinations(std::vector<int> nums, std::vector<int> selected, int n, int r) {
    if (n == 0) {
        all_combinations.push_back(selected);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<int> new_nums;
        std::vector<int> new_selected = selected;
        new_selected.push_back(nums[i]);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); j++) {
            new_nums.push_back(nums[j]);
        }
        get_combinations(new_nums, new_selected, n - 1, r);
    }
}

bool check_validity(std::vector<int> combination) {
    if (combination[0] >= 18 || combination[1] >= 19 || combination[2] <= 24 || combination[3] <= 28 || combination[4] <= 33 || combination[5] <= 47) {
        return false;
    }
    if (combination[0] == 6 || combination[0] == 5) {
        return false;
    }
    if (combination[1] == 14 || combination[1] == 15 || combination[1] == 10) {
        return false;
    }
    if (combination[2] == 24 || combination[2] == 17 || combination[2] == 46 || combination[2] == 18) {
        return false;
    }
    if (combination[3] == 27 || combination[3] == 41 || combination[3] == 29) {
        return false;
    }
    if (combination[4] == 37 || combination[4] == 48 || combination[4] == 50) {
        return false;
    }
    if (combination[5] == 52 || combination[5] == 55) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `main` es un método, así que espera que abras la llave `{` para dar paso a la definición del mismo.

Comment: Gracias, pero entonces donde deberia ponerse la llave, despues del int main ()?

Comment: No sé qué es lo que intentas hacer con ese código y tampoco lo has indicado. En general, el método `main` es el entrypoint (por donde inicia la ejecución del programa); actúa en consecuencia y define qué quieres que haga el programa. Veo unos métodos ahí definidos; no tiene mucho sentido que estén dentro del main.  De nuevo, tu descripción del problema dice mucho de que _estás aprnediendo_ pero no dice nada de qué quieres que haga el código. Puedes [edit] y hacer una pregunta más clara

Comment: Si, una disculpa, ando aprendiendo por mi cuenta y no estoy seguro ni de lo que hago pero lo que itnento hacer es conseguir como resultado multiples combinaciones de 6 numero pero trato de que cumplan condiciones como; si son numeros primos, numeros compuestos, que vayan del 1 al 56, y ademas que las combinaciones finales sean menores o mayores a ciertos numeros que yo diga. No se si me logre dar a entender

Comment: Edita. La. Pregunta.